# Fortran 90 w/ Cygwin: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: cygwin, fortran, gfortran, fault

I've done all of my programming in Matlab until recently when I decided to learn free-form Fortran. I use the gfortran compiler with Cygwin. I'm interested in writing functions that can take an array as an input, do calculations on it, and then pass a new array back out. I never thought this was a difficult task, but it has sure proven to be one at least for me anyway. Here's my simple test code:

```
    PROGRAM RETURN_ARRAY
! Description: This program is used to test a function that returns
!              an array.

    REAL*8 :: NROOT

    PRINT *, NROOT(2, [1.0D0, 4.0D0, 9.0D0, 16.0D0, 25.0D0])

END PROGRAM RETURN_ARRAY


FUNCTION NROOT(N, X) RESULT(Y)
! Description: This function calculates the Nth root of a real number
!              or array of real numbers.
!
! Inputs: N - desired Nth root
!         X - real number or array of real numbers to take Nth root of
!
! Outputs: Y - Nth root of real number or array of real numbers, X

    INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
    REAL*8, INTENT(IN)  :: X(:)
    REAL*8              :: P
    REAL*8              :: Y(SIZE(X))

    P = 1.0D0/N
    Y = X**P

END FUNCTION NROOT
```

`I compile this program and internal function as follows:

```
gfortran RETURN_ARRAY.f90 -o MAIN.exe
```

The program compiles without error. However, when I try to run the program, I get this output in the terminal:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried compiling (gfortran 4.8 on Fedora 18), I first got an error that reads

```
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'n' at (1); passed REAL(8) to INTEGER(4)
```

So there is the first error. Changing the `2.d0` to `2`, I get the following error

```
Error: Procedure 'nroot' at (1) with assumed-shape dummy argument 'x' must have an explicit interface
```

So here is another error. Simply using a `contains` structure (see below), I get the following result:

```
   1.0000000000000000        2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000        4.0000000000000000        5.0000000000000000
```

So it seems your problem is two-fold: you are incorrectly matching variable types & incorrectly declaring a function. The following is what your code should look like (sans comments):

```
PROGRAM RETURN_ARRAY
    PRINT *, NROOT(2, [1.0D0, 4.0D0, 9.0D0, 16.0D0, 25.0D0])
  CONTAINS
    FUNCTION NROOT(N, X) RESULT(Y)
       INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: N
       REAL*8, INTENT(IN)  :: X(:)
       REAL*8              :: P
       REAL*8              :: Y(SIZE(X))

       P = 1.0D0/N
       Y = X**P

    END FUNCTION NROOT
END PROGRAM RETURN_ARRAY
```

**EDIT**

As an aside, I have two other suggestions:

(1) It is bad practice to use `REAL*8` as it is compiler and/or system dependent. You should use `INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(14, 100)` (here `14` signifies the number of significant decimal places and `100` represents the maximal exponent). You would then define variables as `REAL(dp) :: P` or `REAL(KIND=dp) :: P` and `P = 1.0_dp/N`.

(2) You should declare `IMPLICIT NONE` after `PROGRAM <name>`. This way, any variables that are not explicitly declared halt the compiler.

Comment: Thanks kyle. I appreciate your help. I've added more to my reply below.

Comment: I tried to add a more detailed response to your answer but apparently I have to have a reputation of at least 10 to add an answer to my own question. I am aware of the `CONTAINS` structure but using this requires that the function be internal. My attached program is just a test. I'm interested in eventually using the function external to the main program in which case the `CONTAINS` structure wouldn't work.

Comment: @Stephen Make the function a module procedure (put it after the CONTAINS statement in a module) and then USE the module in the main program (or in future in any other program unit that needs to reference the function).

Comment: `REAL*8` isn't compiler or system dependent, it's an 8-byte real `REAL(8)` is compiler/system dependent. (*personal rant*: I hate the `kind` crap, and find the `selected_real_kind` annoying, so I either use the star notation, or for newer Fortran code I just `use ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` and then declare `real(kind=real64)`)

Comment: @steabert: you are right, I always confuse those two options since I never use them; I always use `dp` as I defined it. I rarely delve into `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV` or `ISO_C_BINDING`, so I am far less familiar with those.

Comment: @IanH YOU ARE A LIFESAVER! That's exactly the kind of work around I was looking for. This FORTRAN thing is pretty fun when it works like I expect it to. Thanks everyone for the responses.